# How to disable autocomplete on the wp-login.php page

Tags: login, autocomplete

It looks like there is not an easy way to add autocomplete="off" to the password input on the WordPress login page without editing the wp-login.php page directly.

Is there something I'm missing? I do not want to modify core files.

Comment: This is a PCI compliance issue. No website can pass a PCI compliance scan if the password fields allow autocomplete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your only solution (without modifying core files) is to use JavaScript.

```
function wpse_159462_login_form() {
    echo <<<html
<script>
    document.getElementById( "user_pass" ).autocomplete = "off";
</script>
html;
}

add_action( 'login_form', 'wpse_159462_login_form' );
```

Having said that, if you're not the only one that will be signing in I would advise against disabling autocomplete, it will almost certainly [**** people off](https://blog.0xbadc0de.be/archives/124).

Comment: Where does this go?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone cares this is a solution that worked for me

```
if ( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'wp-login.php' ) {
  ob_start();
}

add_action('login_form', function($args) {
  $login = ob_get_contents();
  ob_clean();
  $login = str_replace('id="user_pass"', 'id="user_pass" autocomplete="off"', $login);
  $login = str_replace('id="user_login"', 'id="user_login" autocomplete="off"', $login);
  echo $login; 
}, 9999);
```

Comment: You can put the ob_start() into the "login_form_login action instead of the if

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with PHP only I come up with:

```
function disable_autofill_password($safe_text, $text) {
    if($safe_text === 'user_pass') {
        $safe_text .= '" autocomplete="new-password';
    }
    return $safe_text;
}
add_filter('attribute_escape', 'disable_autofill_password', 10, 2);
```

It's a little hack of the [`esc_attr`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) filter, it close the `id` attribute of the password input then add the `autocomplete` attribute (the `new-password` value [is used for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30976223/3305116)).

Answer (score 0):

someone has made a plugin to do just that, it's not on WordPress plugins but it's pretty simple and works a treat. Good practice to have a look at the source if you're unsure about plugins not listed on wp plugins, I did and there's nothing nasty in it.

see the code here:
https://www.buzelac.com/2014/10/disabling-wordpress-login-password-autocomplete/

or download the plugin here:
https://www.buzelac.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/disable-login-autocomplete.zip

there's not a lot to it, it simply replaces the `'id="user_pass"'` with `'id="user_pass" autocomplete="off"'` when the login form is generated:

`$content = str_replace('id="user_pass"', 'id="user_pass" autocomplete="off"', $content);`

Answer (score 0):

Try PHP Output Buffering:

```php
add_action('login_header', function () {
    ob_start();
});

add_action('login_footer', function () {
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    $content = str_replace(' name="log"', ' name="log" autocomplete="off"', $content);
    $content = str_replace(' name="pwd"', ' name="pwd" autocomplete="off"', $content);
    echo $content;
});
```

Answer (score -4):

Open your wp-login.php & add autocomplete="off" in "Username" field.
Find form named loginform & add as:

class="input" value="" size="20" autocomplete="off"/>

Comment: He said that he don't want to modify the core files. Also you should never ever modify the core fields.